# How does it work if I had the same name column as Model's name, which is associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Assuming that I had two Models called **User** and **Comment**

And there is a column called **comment** in User Table.

and in association, this is steted

**user.rb**

> has_one :comment

**comment.rb**

> belongs_to :user

What's going to be fetched if I code like this in controller?

> @comment = User.comment

Does it fetch all the associated records from Comment Table?

or does it fetch the content of comment column of User Table???

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you're asking if it's possible to have a column name with the same name as an association, then no, don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the relationship backward, there should be a 'user_id' column in the 'comments' table.  Then your controller code will work as expected - it will fetch the associated comment for that user.  And note that the convention for associations is to name the column 'modelname_id', not just 'modelname'

Comment: Supposing the comment in User table and Comment model itself is made for different purpose

Comment: @MKK, I'm not sure what you mean - can you clarify?

Comment: Umm Sorry about my poor explanation. comment column in User table could be named any, for example 'note' would be fine as different name. I just wanted to name it **comment** because it's the perfect name to understand what it's for. But beside that, I also have the model named **Comment** so that I thought it'll be problem

Comment: Rails associations expect a certain convention to work as you are using them.  As you can see from my answer, you would use `comment_id` instead of `comment`.  Except that then a User would have to be configured to belong_to a Comment (the one holding the foreign key is considered the child in the relationship) - which just seems wrong.  Put a column `user_id` in the comments table and watch it just work.

Comment: Note that these conventions are there to make life easier.  If you are hard set on using 'comment' or 'note' as the column name, you can certainly do that but it requires a few more steps to configure.

Comment: Okay. thanks. Then I'll just name it 'cote' if it makes life easier:) Thanks again